# Updating UI thread from another thread only works on some values

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have an app which does some downloading in another thread. The size of the file is too large to download in the UI thread as it freezes the UI..

Initialize thread:

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(parse));
```

Inside the "parse" async method:
(Reader and Article are methods of the ReadSharp library)

```
source.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
tt.Opacity = 0;
Reader reader = new Reader();
Article article;
article = await reader.Read(new Uri(ids));
tt.Opacity = 0.5;
source.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

featuredimg.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
(Action)(() => { featuredimg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(article.FrontImage.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute)); }));
```

Everything works fine other then the "featuredimg.Source" part of the code. It simply does not update. I tried using the dispatcher with no different results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting that when your `oThread` object completes that the bitmap will be initialized, then that expectation is incorrect. The thread itself will exit as soon as the `parse()` method reaches the `await reader.Read(new Uri(ids));` statement.

All that said, you can at least improve on what you seem to have now. The use of an explicit `Thread` object is unnecessary here and just gets in the way. Instead, you should have something like this:

```
async void someEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await parse();
}

async Task parse()
{
    source.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    tt.Opacity = 0;
    Reader reader = new Reader();
    Article article;
    article = await reader.Read(new Uri(ids));
    tt.Opacity = 0.5;
    source.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

    featuredimg.Source = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri(article.FrontImage.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

In other words, there's no need to call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` when you're dealing with the `async` method, assuming the operation is initiated on the UI thread. You simply `await` as needed for the `Read()` method to complete, and let everything else happen on the UI thread normally.

Variations on the above include simply calling `parse()` as "fire and forget":

```
void someEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _ = parse();
}
```

Or having the `parse()` method actually return the `Article` object and letting the event handler update the bitmap:

```
async void someEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Article article = await parse();

    featuredimg.Source = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri(article.FrontImage.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute));
}

async Task<Article> parse()
{
    source.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    tt.Opacity = 0;
    Reader reader = new Reader();
    Article article;
    article = await reader.Read(new Uri(ids));
    tt.Opacity = 0.5;
    source.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

    return article;
}
```

You can rearrange the code to put UI-related operations in the event handler or the `parse()` method to suit your preference.

Comment: The thread is required because putting the download into the UI thread causes it to lag until the download is completed. Is there any way to delay the thread until the bitmapimage is loaded?

Comment: Without more context, I can't address that concern. However, the `reader.Read()` method _ought_ to be asynchronous (as indicated by the fact that you `await` it). As such, the download should _not_ be blocking the UI thread even without wrapping the call to `parse()` in a new thread.

Comment: Best practice is to **always** use try/catch around any `async` method calls, and to always `await` the return even if it is `void` or you don't need it. This can be done anywhere in the call tree, but is always a good idea inside `async` event handlers. If you don't explicitly catch exceptions, and an exception is thrown, you'll get a random, un-debuggable "Unobserved failure exception" at some future point in time when the GC runs and clears up the failed `Task` object.